# Horror movie about a mask that turned people into demons

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

When I was a kid, I was subjected to a horror movie that I was probably too young to watch and it scared the pants off me.  I remember the plot quite vividly.

A cinema screening was showing a horror film about a mask that turned people into demons, and at the theatre the mask from the movie was on display.  Some people were goofing around with the mask on display and one of them put it on, but when they took it off it cut his/her face.  Later, while everyone was watching the movie, he or she goes to the bathroom and pus starts spewing forth from the wound.  Eventually, that person turns into a demon/zombie who can "infect" others by scratching them.

Before long, everyone in the cinema is a demon except for two people (a man and a woman) who manage to escape on a motorbike.  They discover the entire town is infected but hitch a ride with some people blowing town in a pickup truck.

I'm pretty sure the film was in English, and probably out in the 80s or early 90s.  It probably wasn't a great film, but I'd like to watch it again just because it was the first horror I ever saw.

Does anyone know what it was called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the Dario Argento produced film [Demons](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089013/combined) (1985) about a group of people invited to a free movie screening who are then infected and turn to demons. [This starts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demons_%28film%29) when one character named Rosemary:

> scratches her face with a bizarre display mask before they go in to watch the film. The film is a violent, disturbing horror movie which features a look-alike of the mask from the lobby. [...] Rosemary feels ill and goes to the bathroom, where the scratch on her face bursts open, spewing out pus. She is soon transformed into a bloodthirsty, fanged demon like the one in the film. Rosemary attacks her friend, Carmen, who then rips through the screen and transforms into a demon in front of the rest of the cinema-goers.

Only 2 people remain uninfected near the end and they escape on a jeep. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Thanks.  I feel rather stupid now because I was sure it was called Demons and saw this but didn't think it was the same film because I didn't recognise the box art (I couldn't seem to find the synopsis). :-)